# auth.login is not getting fired at all while calling from localhost and auth.logout is taking long time to get fired after log out

Tags: javascript, facebook

auth.login is not getting fired at all while I am running script from localhost.
And OnceI logged out from facebook after half an hour auth.logout event is getting fired. Can any one tell me the reason and suggest me any thing.
I am doing it in following way:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: "472581889444408",
        status: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
       }); 


    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response){alert("status changed");});
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response){alert("authResponse changed");});
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response){alert("log in");});
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response){alert("log out");});


     };
```

Comment: Can you post some code please? Otherwise, we would just be guessing as to what your issue is.

Comment: Is there any need to provide any extra parameters to FB.init?

Comment: If I have opened facebook in 1 tab and logged in and then load my page then its showing alert of "status changed" and "authResponse changed". But once I logged out its not showing me "log out" alert